# How to avoid HTMLElement.InnerHtml property to change relative path url of HTML elements

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, winforms

In winforms, I have something similar to a HTML editor where a textbox control is used to write Html code and a browser control to display a preview.

I am trying to set an InnerHtml property of a HTMLElement with something like this:

```
htmlElement.InnerHtml = txtCode.Text;
```

The problem is when assigning a string like:

```
 "<a href='/foo/bar.aspx'>Click Here</a>"
```

htmlElement.InnerHtml returns:

```
"<a href=\"file:///C:/foo/bar.aspx\">Click Here</a>"
```

The HTML code of the InnerHtml property is saved in a file and the file is used to render content in a website which renders and invalid link.

Is there any way to avoid this behavior of the InnerHtml property, without saving the text directly from the textbox?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As a workaround you can try to put script block in your txtCode:

```
<script>document.write("<a href='/foo/bar.aspx'>Click Here</a>")</script>
```

Comment: This is a terrible way to do it. `document.write` is 1990s technology, and plus, it doesn't work once the page finishes loading. If you're going to use a `<script>` tag, at least do it the right way. Use jQuery, or something like this: `var a = document.createElement('a'); a.href="/your/url.aspx"; a.innerHTML = 'A suitable link (not "click here")'; document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(a);` (This is from memory and may not be exact.)

Comment: I don't see the reason to stick bunch of JavaScript code in to something that can be used by non technical people. 1990 technology is still pretty solid by this date. and document.write() is very short and descriptive. You can go ahead and load ~250 Kb of "junk" for something simple like this work around, but I do believe in old school where the space and memory is limited and should not be wasted without the very good reason to do so.

Comment: The moment they try to use a library that uses AttachEvent or AddEventListener (or whatever it is), their functions will stop working and they'll be 100% clueless why. You're leading them to the pit of failure through trying to dumb it down. Also, `document.write`, as I said, causes the page to clear if done after the page finishes loading. You're not helping anyone with that! You're just making them more likely to get frustrated and fail.

Comment: "Here, let me show you a technique that is dead simple for your narrow use-case. Just be aware that you can't do this as a real web developer. And if you ever try anything outside of this narrow case then it will blow up in your face." That's what you're doing, but you're not even warning people about it. That's why I object.

Comment: I like your last comment. It is a narrow use-case, There is a bug in contenteditable in MS WebControl where it doesn't let you use relative anchor tags. So yes, it isn't real life web development so to say, but your Event attachment to appendChild(a) doesn't fly ether.

Comment: My event attachment? What? Hmmm I do think I got your post and another one I recently commented on mixed up. Sorry to bring up event attachment, though that would still be a problem with your code if events were involved.

Answer (score 1):

My only idea is to delete the text node child of the `<a>` element, and then append a newly-created text node with your text. This might work around whatever process is interfering with your assignment of `InnerHtml`.